# Dynamically updating ng-repeat for matrix

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, page-refresh

I have matrix(2D array) `cells` in model, what I represent in a table.

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in cells track by $index'>
    <td ng-repeat='cell in row track by $index'>
        {{cell}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want add a drop down buttons to resize length and width,

```
<select ng-model="length"  >
    <option ng-repeat="size in sizes" ng-click="setLength(size)">{{size}}       </option>
</select>
```

but can't refresh `ng-repeat`. For refresh page I use `$scope.$apply()` after set new matrix in `cells`

```
$scope.cells = new Array($scope.width);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cells.length; i++) {
        $scope.cells[i] = new Array($scope.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.length; j++) {
            $scope.cells[i][j] = 'cell';
        }
    }

$scope.$apply();
```

but it doesn't help. How to refresh `ng-repeat`?

P.S. When user is changing size matrix, it should back to default values with new size.

[my demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/L00ototL/1/)

Comment: your demo is missing data, and this question is missing the code from demo

Comment: @smnbbrv when user is changing size matrix it should back to default values with new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle your 2D array is not created corretly. Please have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) for tips how to setup the array.

I've changed these points of your code:

- used `ng-options` for length and width dropdown. That's easier than `ng-repeat`.
- Removed click events from the width and length drop down and added a `$watch` for width and length scope variables for updating the map.
- Updated creation of 2d array.

Below is a working demo of your code or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/L00ototL/3/).

```js
var myapp = angular.module('mapApp', []);

myapp.controller('editorController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.cells = [
        []
    ];
    $scope.sizes = [];

    makeSizes();

    $scope.length = $scope.sizes[0];
    $scope.width = $scope.sizes[0];
 
    $scope.$watch('[width,length]', makeMap, true);

    function makeMap() {
        var cols = $scope.width,
            rows = $scope.length;
  console.log('makeMap');
        $scope.cells = matrix(rows, cols, 'cell');
    }

    function matrix(rows, cols, defaultValue) {
  // code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript
        var arr = [[]];

        // Creates all lines:
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            // Creates an empty line
            arr[i] = [];

            // Adds cols to the empty line:
            arr[i] = new Array(cols);

            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                // Initializes:
                arr[i][j] = defaultValue;
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

    makeMap();

    function makeSizes() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.sizes.push(i + 3);
        }
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="editorController">
    <label>Length</label>
    <select ng-model="length" ng-options="length for length in sizes">
        </select>
    <table>
    <label>Width</label>
    <select ng-model="width" ng-options="width for width in sizes">
        </select>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in cells track by $index">
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index">
                    {{cell}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```